# how to change the TextBox width dynamically based on text length in UWP?

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

What I have tried is?

```
TextBox box=new TextBox{Height=32};
box.TextChanged += TextChanged;
private void TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
   //whenever the textbox text changed,i want to set the width of textbox to current text lenght
}
```

I Don't know ,how to achieve this?Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The default behavior of `TextBox` is to change the width of the control according to the length of the internal text.

If `TextBox.Width` is not explicitly set, then TextBox will be adjusted between `MinWidth` and `MaxWidth`.

Like this:

```xml
<Grid x:Name="RootGrid">
</Grid>
```

```cs
var box = new TextBox();
box.Height = 32;
box.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
RootGrid.Children.Add(box);
```

*If you place the TextBox in the Grid, you need to explicitly set the HorizontalAlignment to Left*

---

**Update**

If you want to be consistent with the current text width, this can also be achieved without listening to the `TextBox.TextChanged` event. We can try to modify the control template of the `TextBox` to remove the delete button.

```xml
<Style TargetType="TextBox" x:Name="CustomTextBoxStyle">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlForeground}" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBackground}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBorderBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="SelectionHighlightColor" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlSelectionHighlightColor}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBorderThemeThickness}" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode" Value="Auto" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode" Value="Auto" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Hidden" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Hidden" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlThemePadding}" />
    <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="{ThemeResource IsApplicationFocusVisualKindReveal}" />
    <Setter Property="ContextFlyout" Value="{StaticResource TextControlCommandBarContextFlyout}" />
    <Setter Property="SelectionFlyout" Value="{StaticResource TextControlCommandBarSelectionFlyout}" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                <Grid>

                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />

                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">

                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HeaderContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlHeaderForegroundDisabled}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBackgroundDisabled}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBorderBrushDisabled}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlForegroundDisabled}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{Binding PlaceholderForeground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, TargetNullValue={ThemeResource TextControlPlaceholderForegroundDisabled}}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>

                                    <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">

                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBorderBrushPointerOver}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBackgroundPointerOver}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{Binding PlaceholderForeground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, TargetNullValue={ThemeResource TextControlPlaceholderForegroundPointerOver}}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlForegroundPointerOver}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Focused">

                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{Binding PlaceholderForeground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, TargetNullValue={ThemeResource TextControlPlaceholderForegroundFocused}}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBackgroundFocused}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBorderBrushFocused}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlForegroundFocused}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="RequestedTheme">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Light" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>

                                </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="HeaderContentPresenter"
                    Grid.Row="0"
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                    Content="{TemplateBinding Header}"
                    ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}"
                    FontWeight="Normal"
                    Foreground="{ThemeResource TextControlHeaderForeground}"
                    Margin="{ThemeResource TextBoxTopHeaderMargin}"
                    TextWrapping="Wrap"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                    Visibility="Collapsed"
                    x:DeferLoadStrategy="Lazy" />
                    <Border x:Name="BorderElement"
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    Grid.RowSpan="1"
                    Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                    CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding CornerRadius}"
                    Control.IsTemplateFocusTarget="True"
                    MinWidth="{ThemeResource TextControlThemeMinWidth}"
                    MinHeight="{ThemeResource TextControlThemeMinHeight}" />
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="ContentElement"
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    HorizontalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode}"
                    HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"
                    VerticalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode}"
                    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility}"
                    IsHorizontalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled}"
                    IsVerticalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled}"
                    IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled}"
                    Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                    Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    IsTabStop="False"
                    AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"
                    ZoomMode="Disabled" />
                    <TextBlock x:Name="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter"
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                    Foreground="{Binding PlaceholderForeground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, TargetNullValue={ThemeResource TextControlPlaceholderForeground}}"
                    Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                    Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                    Text="{TemplateBinding PlaceholderText}"
                    TextAlignment="{TemplateBinding TextAlignment}"
                    TextWrapping="{TemplateBinding TextWrapping}"
                    IsHitTestVisible="False" />
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="DescriptionPresenter"
                    Grid.Row="2"
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                    Content="{TemplateBinding Description}"
                    Foreground="{ThemeResource SystemControlDescriptionTextForegroundBrush}"
                    AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"
                    x:Load="False"/>

                </Grid>

            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

```cs
var box = new TextBox();
box.Height = 32;
box.Padding = new Thickness(0);
box.Style = CustomTextBoxStyle;
box.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
RootGrid.Children.Add(box);
```

For TextBox, the text width is not easy to calculate, because the internal font cannot be guaranteed to be a monospace font, so it is a feasible solution to use the characteristics of the control itself to achieve the goal.

Comment: yeah.you ae right.but instead of that i want to change width to current text length width while text changed evnt.is there any way?

Comment: If you want to be consistent with the current text width, this can also be achieved without listening to the `TextBox.TextChanged` event. We can try to modify the control template of the `TextBox` to remove the delete button. I have updated the answer, please check.

Comment: It is still unable to shrink the width smaller than 60 px by auto width.